# inventory control for magento bundle product

Tags: bundle, product

I have several package products created with your options. I take much control the stock of the main item an example: I created a product package called desktop X-10C model and within it its accessories. But sometimes only a part of the X-10C model and I sell it the package will continue active selling more x-10C. What I want some module or programming so I can add to my inventory control product package. Control the stock of the product package. Can anyone tell me?

Comment: We realise that English is not your first language.  But it is really difficult to understand what you are asking.  It is possible for you to rephrase it,  Try using shorter sentences.

Comment: This kind of question is off topic for StackOverflow. You might have more luck on the [Magento StackExchange](http://magento.stackexchange.com) though.